# R how to extract datasets from a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have the following dataframes that are stored in a list as a result of using the map() function:

[image]

How can I extract the six dataframes from the list? I would like to do this because I would like to give each column a different name of the dataframe and then store all data in a csv file? Or do I not have to extract the dfs from the list then?

Comment: `dats1[[1]]` to access the first element of the list.

Comment: do you want to append them in one `data.frame`?

Comment: What's the output you're trying to get exactly? Try to make this [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about what you are exactly looking for, so below are something just from guessing your objective:

- If you want to extract the data frame as objects in your global environment, then you can do like this:

```
list2env(setNames(dats1,paste0("df",seq(dats1))),envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

- Assuming you are giving names `"col1"` and`"col2"` to two columns of different data frames in your list, maybe this can help you

```
dats1 <- lapply(dats1, setNames, c("col1","col2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options

Fake data

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a = 1:9,b = letters[1:9])


x <- list(df,df,df,df)
```

You can bind dfs and create just one

```
bind_rows(x)
```

You can execute your logic on all dfs

```
logic <- . %>% 
  mutate(c = a*3)

x %>% map(logic)
```

You can can also name the dfs inside the list

```
names(x) <- letters[1:4]

bind_rows(x,.id = "id")
```